# How do you make a <textarea> recognize that pushing the enter button is a \n character?

Tags: javascript, html

I have a `<textarea>` that I want to print the contents on the page below it. When it does this I want to make random words be omitted.

I have accomplished this. My problem is I want make it recognize when the enter button has been pushed in the `<textarea>` and display that below. I want those to not ever be omitted. I have gotten it so that when a `<br/>` is typed into the `<textarea>` it will not omit those and it will show the new lines. When I tried doing that with the `\n` it does not seem to recognize in the `.value` of the object that the enters are `\n`.

Any ideas how to fix this?

I also tried `var txtAdd = document.getElementById('textLoc').value.replace("\n","<br/>");` and it did not work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe ".replace(/\n/g, '<br />');"?

Comment: Possibly `/\r?\n/g` would be better, in case a browser inserts a CR LF sequence.

Comment: Ah, it's the crazy old 'replace doesn't actually replace' gotcha/WTF. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3926610/javascript-jquery-gotchas/3927400#3927400

Answer (score 0):

I don't follow what you are trying to do, but is it possible that you need \r\n since that is the equivalent of newline on a windows machine (assuming you are running windows)?

Answer (score 0):

I think its about way of saving the data first time you should use innerHTML property that you can save it with  with out replacing with \n

Regards 
Marwan