# Detrimental Javascript Tricks

Tags: javascript

What are some of the most detrimental Javascript tricks?  Pleas include the **"issue seen"** and "**avoid by**" blocks.

Examples:

1. Adding properties to `Object.prototype.prop = 1`
   **Issue seen**: `for(var i in obj){ alert(i);}`
   **Avoid by**: using `hasOwnProperty`
   example:
   `for(var in in obj)if(obj.hasOwnProperty(i)){alert(i);}`
2. Override `Number.prototype.valueOf = function(){return Math.random()}`
   **Issue seen**: `4*3` (Depends on Javascript engine)
   **Avoid by**:  `delete Number.prototype.valueof` (again depends on Javascript engine)

Please include potential solutions if you can't think of a way to "**avoid**" the code.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Javascript/jQuery "Gotchas"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3926610/javascript-jquery-gotchas)

Comment: @Quentin But I liked the Devil tag ;D

Comment: @Lime — You might like it, but it had **nothing** to do with the question. *Developer's Image Library (DevIL) is a programmer's library to develop applications with very powerful image loading capabilities, yet is easy for a developer to learn and use*

Comment: @Lime interesting how the `devil` tag didn't have any followers :-/

Comment: http://programmers.stackexchange.com/ anyone?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just read Crock's appendix, ["JavaScript, the bad parts"](http://oreilly.com/javascript/excerpts/javascript-good-parts/bad-parts.html)

Comment: Don't forget the Awful Parts appendix too!

Comment: Yeah Crock's appendix is good, but I was looking more towards 'user error'/'intentional user error' and not syntax/language confusion.

Comment: @Lime, a few of the things he mentions are rife for user error, such as `switch` fall through, blockless statements, `&` instead of `&&`, forgetting `new`.